# OpenMP: No Speedup in parallel workloads

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

So I can't really figure this bit out with my fairly simple OpenMP parallelized for loop. When running on the same input size, P=1 runs in ~50 seconds, but running P=2 takes almost 300 Seconds, with P=4 running ~250 Seconds.

Here's the parallelized loop

```
double time = omp_get_wtime();

printf("Input Size: %d\n", n);

#pragma omp parallel for private(i) reduction(+:in)
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double x = (double)(rand() % 10000)/10000;
    double y = (double)(rand() % 10000)/10000;
    if(inCircle(x, y)) {
        in++;
    }
}

double ratio = (double)in/(double)n;
double est_pi = ratio * 4.0;
time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
```

Runtimes:

p=1, n=1073741824 - 52.764 seconds

p=2, n=1073741824 - 301.66 seconds

p=4, n=1073741824 - 274.784 seconds

p=8, n=1073741824 - 188.224 seconds

Running in a Ubuntu 20.04 VM with 8 cores of a Xeon 5650 and 16gb of DDR3 EEC RAM on top of a FreeNas installation on a Dual Xeon 5650 System with 70Gb of RAM.

Partial Solution:

The rand() function inside of the loop causes the time to jump when running on multiple threads.

Comment: Maybe the rand() function based on the last run of the of the method to make the next random number. Then it will be the bottle neck because it is thread save. Set x and y to static values and make the time messurment again please.

Comment: That does seem to fix the problem. Do you know how to call rand() inside of a parallelized loop? It's a requirement for the estimation of pi that I'm doing.

Comment: I would say ditch the rand(), it's thread safety is implementation-defined, i got quite nice results by creating instance of a random number generator for each thread (~2.0s serial, ~0.6s on 6 cores)

Answer (score 3):

Since `rand()` uses state saved from the previous call to generated the next PRN it can't run in multiple threads at the same time.  Multiple threads would need to read/write the PRNG state at the same time.

[POSIX states that `rand()` need not be thread safe.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand.html)  This means your code could just not work right.  Or the C library might put in a mutex so that only one thread could call `rand()` at a time.  This is what's happening, but it slows the code down considerably.  The threads are nearly entirely consumed trying to get access to the rand critical section as nothing else they are doing takes any significant time.

To solve this, try using `rand_r()`, which does not use shared state, but instead is passed the `seed` value it should use for state.

Keep in mind that using the same seed for every thread will defeat the purpose of increasing the number of trials in your Monte Carlo simulation.  Each thread would just use the exact same pseudo-random sequence.  Try something like this:

```
unsigned int seed;
#pragma omp parallel private(seed)
{
    seed = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp for private(i) reduction(+:in)
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double x = (double)(rand_r(&seed) % 10000)/10000;
        double y = (double)(rand_r(&seed) % 10000)/10000;
        if(inCircle(x, y)) {
            in++;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you might notice your estimate is off.  x and y need to be evenly distributed in the range [0, 1], and they are not.

Comment: Also go and read "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1,2,3" : http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf